# Used motor and trans in my 09 escape limited 2.5l. Does it need to be reflashed?

Tags: automatic-transmission, ignition-switch, electronic-control-module

It will start if starter relay is jumped and stay running but will not Shift into gear.
Replaced the starter switch with new one and new starter relay. No power to the starter switch as I tried to start it with the switch itself. Grounds have all been checked and so has all the relays and resistors.